# Mockolate: Suddenly getting VerifyError: illegal override

Tags: apache-flex, flash, mockolate

I started using mockolate to write my unit tests a few weeks back, and up 'till now it's worked great.  All of a sudden, last night, I started getting errors like the following on every test that uses mockolate:

```
VerifyError: Error #1053: Illegal override of IContextMenuBuilder17E13646AD898E2616969BF920CF08CD49997F2F in asmock.generated.IContextMenuBuilder17E13646AD898E2616969BF920CF08CD49997F2F.

at global$init()
```

In reading, it seems like this error is typically due to different swfs/swcs being compiled on different versions of the sdk, but both my mockolate swc and my source are being compiled on the same sdk version, and that hasn't changed in quite a while.  I've even tried just including mockolate as a source in my project, and just including it's swcs as lib paths.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

-Hob

Answer (score 0):

I received a similar error when using `mockolate` from within Flash Builder 4.7.  What worked for me was to do a clean on my project.  After that, I re-ran my tests and had no problems.